# What prompted the change in Anissa's personality?

Tags: dc, black-lightning-2018

In the third season, Anissa is helping some metahumans escape from the military regime in Freeland. She's made a deal to shelter them with some of the Perdi, who have a farm and whom she had previously helped. However, the latter group are not entirely comfortable with potentially bringing the wrath of the ASA and the Markovian forces down upon them. When they tell Anissa as much, she lifts up and chokes the emphatically non-superpowered and elderly patriarch, and hits another person hard enough to be potentially lethal. Further, when one these same friends then accuses her as being almost as bad as the Sange (a gang of neo-Confederates led by an evil metahuman), she promises that she could be *worse*.

Obviously, Anissa has never been guided by the traditional superhero morality that guides her father. In the previous season, she showed herself quite willing to go on the offensive and use potentially lethal attacks against gang members and such, whereas Jefferson would not even kill his archenemy, Tobias Whale, when he had the chance. Still, attacking violent criminals with lethal force is somewhat distinct from doing the same to one's friends.

What, if anything, is behind Anissa's change in strategy?

Comment: Title says "personality", question says "strategy". Which is it?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Well, the truth is that I am not sure which one it is. Is she engaging in calculated intimidation to try to safeguard her efforts, or has she simply decided that she doesn't care so much about hurting her friends and allies? Or a little of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evidence suggests that this is an intentional strategy, with her maybe having gone a bit overboard.

Later in the series, Anissa says that she has done things that she is not proud of in order to keep her "Underground Railroad" functioning. Presumably, threatening the Perdi to continue helping her would be one of them. Since there's not much indication in the rest of the season of her having changed her moral outlook significantly, it seems likely that it was (mostly) just bluster. In fact, when the Markovians inevitably attack the Perdi farm, she takes responsibility for it.